# org.json.JSONException: No value for

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I get this error in logcat while fetch json data

org.json.JSONException: No value for alberrnews

also I'm using Retrofit 2 and I don't know if I posted baseurl in right way or not

JsonArray

```
{"alberrnews":[{"title":"This is a title","subject":"This is a subject","image":"http:\/\/www.vcvcvc.com\/uploaded44\/33707\/61457017225.jpg"}]}
```

Main class

```
public class alberrClassNews extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<alberrNewsListContent> alberrNews = new ArrayList<alberrNewsListContent>();
private final String TAG = "Get JSONArray";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alberrnewsclass, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("Main Class");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.alberrNewsList);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    final alberrNewsAdapter aNA = new alberrNewsAdapter(getActivity(), alberrNews);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(aNA);


    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
    progressDialog.show();

    final Retrofit alberrRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://mm.com/alrass_charties/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    alberrService service = alberrRetrofit.create(alberrService.class);


    Call<JSONObject> call = service.alberrNews();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.i(TAG, "success");

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.body().getJSONArray("alberrnews");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    alberrNewsListContent newsContent = new alberrNewsListContent();

                    newsContent.setAlberrNewsTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                    newsContent.setAlberrNewsSubject(jsonObject.getString("subject"));
                    newsContent.setAlberrNewsImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                    alberrNews.add(newsContent);
                }


                aNA.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed");
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "no connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    return view;

}
}
```

service class

```
public interface alberrService {
@GET("alberr_news.php")
Call <JSONObject> alberrNews();
}
```

error in logcat

```
    03-09 04:08:43.617 18686-18696/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-09 04:08:43.656 18686-18686/? I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
03-09 04:08:43.681 18686-18705/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-09 04:08:43.712 18686-18686/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
03-09 04:08:43.765 18686-18705/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-09 04:08:43.766 18686-18705/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-09 04:08:43.771 18686-18705/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-09 04:08:43.812 18686-18705/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-09 04:08:43.857 18686-18705/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-09 04:08:43.890 18686-18705/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-09 04:08:43.890 18686-18705/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3d0fea0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-09 04:08:48.667 18686-18705/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-09 04:08:48.667 18686-18705/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3d0eae0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-09 04:08:49.164 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities I/Get JSONArray: success
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for alberrnews
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities.alberrClassNews$1.onResponse(alberrClassNews.java:74)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:66)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
03-09 04:08:49.165 18686-18686/com.example.abdulmajeed.alrasscharities W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

=================================================================================

Comment: Log the `response` object and post it here.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @ramy inside your `onResponse` method , you have this line :  `JSONArray jsonArray = response.body().getJSONArray("alberrnews");` . See this `response.body()`? Do something like `Log.i("Response Body", response.body().toString())` and post the content of this `response.body()` here

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I/Response Body: {}

Comment: So I guess the error you are getting is pretty clear. Your response is returning empty, although it returns success (probably because of a `200` status code). There are many possibilities here that could cause your error.. from server-side problems to client-side. Some of these could be 1)wrong URL, 2)Wrong parameters passed via GET or POST 3)server handling data badly and returning nothing etc

Comment: @RafaelCardoso URL is like this : http://******.com/alrass_charties/alberr_news.php , I posted (http://******.com/alrass_charties/) inside baseUrl and (alberr_news.php) inside  alberrService class as above, is it right?

Comment: No, it is not correct. Change your baseURL to `http://******.com` and in your interface, change to `@GET("alrass_charties/alberr_news.php")`

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Doesn't work either, any other solution please?

Comment: @ramy What happens if you try to access this URL manually via a broswer (such as Google Chrome)?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I get JsonArray as I posted in the question

Comment: @ramy I dont know. I dont have experience with RetroFit. Why dont you use a simpler library, such as Apache `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
 public interface alberrService {
     @Headers({"content-type: application/json"})
    @GET("alberr_news.php")
    Call <JSONObject> alberrNews();
    }
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: No value for alberrnews